# How can I add where in the conditional aggregation mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot, aggregate

My query like this :

```
SELECT a.number, a.description, b.attribute_code, b.attribute_value 
FROM items a 
JOIN attr_maps b ON b.number = a.number WHERE a.number = AB123
```

If the query executed, the result like this :

[image]

I want to make the result like this :

[image]

I use conditional aggregation like this :

```
SELECT i.number, i.description,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'brand' then am.attribute_value END) as brand,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'model' then am.attribute_value END) as model,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'category' then am.attribute_value END) as category,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'subcategory' then am.attribute_value END) as subcategory
FROM items i JOIN
     attr_maps am
     ON am.number = i.number
WHERE i.number = AB123
GROUP BY i.number, i.description
```

It works

But i'm still confused to add `where` condition. So I want it can filter by brand etc

I try like this :

```
SELECT i.number, i.description,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'brand' then am.attribute_value END) as brand,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'model' then am.attribute_value END) as model,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'category' then am.attribute_value END) as category,
       MAX(CASE WHEN am.attribute_code = 'subcategory' then am.attribute_value END) as subcategory
FROM items i JOIN
     attr_maps am
     ON am.number = i.number
WHERE brand = 'honda'
GROUP BY i.number, i.description
```

There exist error `Unknown column 'brand' in 'where clause'`

How can I solve the error?

Comment: You can't use an alias in a `WHERE` clause. Use `HAVING brand='honda'` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last part of your query

```
WHERE brand = 'honda'
GROUP BY i.number, i.description
```

to

```
GROUP BY i.number, i.description
HAVING brand = 'honda'
```

Comment: @EvE Great. It works