# How to denormalize a table?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

How would I select data from a normalized table with a categorical column and present them as a "railroad table", i.e. "train-stop time1 time2 time3", etc.?

The data are stored as:

```
id, 
panel, 
panel_version, 
gene, 
...
```

I am looking for a way to generate:

```
gene  panel_version_1  panel_version2  panel_version3
```

I tried a method of pivoting in MySQL (using GROUP_CONCAT and CASE), but the result was

```
geneA 1  0  0 
geneA 0  1  0
geneA 0  0  1

geneB ...
```

whereas I want to see:

```
geneA 1  1  1
geneB 0  1  1
geneC 1  0  1
etc.
```

Is this feasible in MySQL?

Comment: This is called Pivoting.

Comment: or more specifically, conditional aggregation.  there's a good example in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240571 (though that's not a duplicate, they are already doing it and asking how to do something else)